# 2 tuple wxpython

Tags: python, user-interface, bitmap, wxpython

I've been working on a menu interface where I'm hoping to use a background and then custom images as buttons, however can't get them to display

```
import wx
import pygame
import os

class menu(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Compsci Vs. Sheep: The Game',size=(640,640))#defining the properties of the window
        MainPanel=wx.Panel(self)

        image_file='main_screen.jpeg'
        bmp=wx.Bitmap(image_file)
        self.bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY, bmp, (0, 0))

        PlayButton=wx.Bitmap('exit.jpeg', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        self.PlayButton=wx.BitmapButton(self.bitmap, -1, PlayButton, pos=())
        self.Bind=(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.closeMe, self.PlayButton)
        self.PlayButton.SetDefault()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE,self.closecorner)

    def closeMe(self,event):
        self.Destroy()

    def closecorner(self,event):
        self.Destroy()
        pygame.mixer.quit()#defining all events 


if __name__=='__main__':
    pygame.mixer.init(frequency=22050, size=-16, channels=2, buffer=4096)
    pygame.mixer.music.load("exorcist.ogg")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame=menu(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Can anyone shed some light on why I keep getting an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "/Users/Matthew/Desktop/pygame sheep/interface.py", line 35, in <module>
    frame=menu(parent=None,id=-1)
  File "/Users/Matthew/Desktop/pygame sheep/interface.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.PlayButton=wx.BitmapButton(self.bitmap, -1, PlayButton, pos=())
  File "/usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode-2.8.12.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-mac-unicode/wx/_controls.py", line 192, in __init__
    _controls_.BitmapButton_swiginit(self,_controls_.new_BitmapButton(*args, **kwargs))
TypeError: Expected a 2-tuple of integers or a wxPoint object.
```

I'm running Python 2.7.2, wxPython 2.8.12

Comment: `()` is not the tuple operator, `,` is (when it doesn't mean something else, like an argument separator). Thus `()`, in an expression is just "bogus syntax". There is no literal syntax for a "0-tuple".

Comment: You also need to get rid of the `=` sign in this line: `self.Bind=(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.closeMe, self.PlayButton)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
self.PlayButton=wx.BitmapButton(self.bitmap, -1, PlayButton, pos=())
                                                             ^^^^^^
```

This isn't valid - you either need to give it a tuple such as `(0, 0)` or don't specify `pos` and let it default.

Comment: I can't believe how stupid I was, I was coming back to the position

Answer (score 0):

`self.PlayButton=wx.BitmapButton(self.bitmap, -1, PlayButton, pos=())`

This line is the problem. The position needs to be a tuple `(x, y)`

Comment: I've now got another error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Matthew/Desktop/pygame sheep/interface.py", line 35, in <module>
    frame=menu(parent=None,id=-1)
  File "/Users/Matthew/Desktop/pygame sheep/interface.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE,self.closecorner)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: @MatthewRhysJones Because there's two forms of bind and you're not using the right one  - read up on http://wiki.wxpython.org/self.Bind%20vs.%20self.button.Bind

Comment: What is `self.closecorner`? It is probably a tuple and not a callable attribute.

Comment: It was meant to be for when you click the corner button so that the music from pygame would stop playing